# Numerically solving this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have to solve an initial value problem governed by the PDE:

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} = A(s) v$ with boundary condition $v_0(t)=v(0,t)$ and $v = v(s,t)$.

It is known that $A(s)$ is a linear operator that acts on $v$. I first used the basic Euler's method to solve this, but $v$ begins to explode after a while. Here is a plot that shows that I am saying:

[image]

I am plotting the norm of $v(s,t)$ as a function of $s$. It seems to become unstable just after 20. Then I used the improved euler's method to solve the same and I noticed that it still "explodes", but the explosion starts after 40. I do not know if the PDE is stiff.

So my question is, what is the best way to solve for some $v(L)$ for such PDEs? I was given the suggestion of using something like

$v(s+h,t) = exp(h A(s)) v(s,t)$, but I am not convinced if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: If $A(s)$ is positive definite then you should expect that the solution grows no?

Comment: It is not positive definite (or doesn't have to be in general). Also, in that case, wouldn't one expect the solution to grow from the start and not suddenly from some point?

Comment: Please, clarify what you call "initial conditon $v_0$ ". Is it $v_0=v(s,0)=v_0(s)$ ? Is $v_0$ a given function of $s$ ?

Comment: My bad. $v_0 = v(0,t)$. I would like to calculate $v(L,t)$

Comment: Apologies for a comment that may be naïve, but a brief search just now on Wikipedia suggests the improved Euler method to be an *explicit* two-stage Runge-Kutta method and as such "generally unsuitable for the solution of stiff equations ... especially important in the solution of partial differential equations." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Implicit_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods

Comment: Not a naive comment at all. I realized that, but I guess my question is: what's the right way to solve this ivp?

Comment: @Paddy. According to your comment I corrected the condition (which isn't an initial condition because $t\neq 0$) in your question. Check if it is OK now. The graph seems not consistent with the condition. What are the variables on the axis of the graph ?. There is still something fishy in the wording of the question.

Comment: One thing I will do is compute/estimate the real part of eigenvalues of $A(s)$ and see whether any of them become positive at $s \sim 25$. The log of norm of your $v$ looks linear between $30$ and $80$, it suggests your $v$ has been dominated by an eigenvector of $A(s)$ for such $s$.

Answer (score 1):

My detective hat is on. According to the title and the first line this is supposed to be a question about PDEs. But in the comments we are told that $A(s)$ is a matrix. So I'm going to guess that a particular discretisation of variable $t$ has already been chosen, and that matrix $A(s)$ is the operator of interest as approximated in that discretisation.

Then our problem really is for an $s$-dependent vector of values. Let's call it $\boldsymbol{u}$. The equation we want to solve is
\begin{equation*}
  \boldsymbol{u}' (s) = A(s)\boldsymbol{u}(s).
\end{equation*}
Now you've tried the forward Euler method already. I'm guessing that the equation you used to find $\boldsymbol{u}(s+\delta s)$ given $\boldsymbol{u}(s)$ looked like this:
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{u}(s+\delta s) = \boldsymbol{u}(s) + A(s)\boldsymbol{u}(s)
\delta s.
\end{equation*}
That would be an *explicit* method. But as discussed in the comments, explicit methods may lead to numerical instabilities. To construct an *implicit* method we would instead work with
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{u}(s+\delta s) =
\boldsymbol{u}(s) + A(s+\delta s)\boldsymbol{u}(s+\delta s)\delta s.
\end{equation*}
Of course this involves solving a system of linear equations at each time step:
\begin{equation*}
  \boldsymbol{u}(s+\delta s) = \left(I-A\!\left(s+\delta s\right)\delta s\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{u}(s).
\end{equation*}
(I'm not suggesting that you actually invert the matrix. That would be inefficient. Merely solve for your particular $\boldsymbol{u}(s)$.)

Comment: I would also favor the numerical instability hypothesis. Note that both proposed expressions of $\boldsymbol{u}(s+\delta s)$ approximate JJacquelin's analytical expression $$
\exp\left(\int_s^{s+\delta s} A(\sigma)\, d\sigma\right) \boldsymbol{u}(s)
$$
using either a left- or right Riemann sum approximation of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the correct wording of the problem is :
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} = A(s) v$$
with condition $v_0(t)=v(0,t)$ and $v = v(s,t)$,

The analytic solution would be :

This is a separable ODE wrt the variable $s$ with parameter $t$ . Integration wrt $s$ leads to :
$$\ln[v(s,t)|=\int_{\sigma=0}^{\sigma=s} A(\sigma)d\sigma+\text{(constant wrt }s)$$
$$v(s,t)=C(t)\exp\left(\int_{\sigma=0}^{\sigma=s} A(\sigma)d\sigma \right)$$
Condition :
$$v_0(t)=v(0,t)=C(t)\exp\left(\int_0^0 A(\sigma)d\sigma\right)=C(t)$$
Result :
$$v(s,t)=v_0(t)\exp\left(\int_{0}^{s} A(\sigma)d\sigma \right)$$

This seems not consistent with the graph insofar the boundary condition $v_0(t)=v(0,t)$ is not itself "exploding". You should carefully rewrite the question and give a reproducible example with given functions $A(s)$ and $v_0(t)$ so that everybody could do the numerical calculus and compare the result with your graph.

IN ADDITION after the comment from Ali :

For example, with $\quad A(s)=-2s\quad$ and $\quad v_0(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}\quad$ the result is
$$v(s,t)=\frac{e^{-s^2}}{t^2+1}$$
It is obvious that this function satisfies the PDE $\quad\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} = A(s) v\quad$ and satisfies the specified condition.
There is no inconsistency with this example. And there is no "explosion" at all.

If Paddy observes an unexpected "explosion" this means that with is own example there is probably an inconsistency in the wording of his question or this is due to the functions $A(s)$ and $v_0(t)$ used in his numerical calculus. It is not possible to say more without a more detailed description of the calculus leading to the graph joint to the question.

Comment: I downvoted this because I don't see the inconsistency that you do. Agreed there should be no "explosion" in the initial condition (presumably you mean in the $t$ direction). But the graph of the norm seems to reflect that.

Comment: @Ali. Without a reproducible numerical example it is not easy to show what is the inconsistency I suspect. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . If Paddy provides the functions $A(s)$ and $v_0(t)$ used in the numerical calculus to compute and to plot the curve draw in his question I could check and see whether the concerns are relevant or not.

Comment: @Ali. See the addition to my main answer.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I appreciate the answer. I think the idea you have is essentially right. It is a little difficult to add the entire problem into the question because of how many pages it might take to describe the algorithm. But what you said makes perfect sense. I do have to add that $A(s)$, in my case, is a matrix operator. This matrix does not have an analytical form and is derived from a different algorithm. Before I accept your answer, would you say that the exponential of the matrix is taken in the "usual" way which is elementwise exponential?

Comment: @JJacquelin I have assumed throughout that Paddy is trying to solve something mathematically sensible. And we already know that the precise point at which the solution starts to blow up depends on the algorithm used (Euler vs. improved Euler, both explicit methods, both prone to numerical instability). Given the obvious conclusion that these blow-ups are caused by numerical instability, I'm not at all sure what you hope to prove by solving a toy example analytically. Did you downvote me in retaliation?

Comment: @Paddy. Well, I realize that the problem is more wide involving matrix equations. Moreover the analytic solving with continuous functions has to be transformed into discret numerical calculus. All this changes the perspectives. So my answer may  lead to new ideas but don't really answers definitively to your question. So I suggest that you don't accept in order to let open for further more pertinent answers.

Comment: @Paddy If you're sure you want to go down this path you should know that a matrix exponential is not performed elementwise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential